# How can i keep my data of mariadb on docker after migrate it to another machine?

Tags: docker, mariadb, mediawiki

I was using a dockerized mariadb container (connected to mediawiki) with default setting(`docker run --name some-mariadb -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mariadb:tag`). And now i need to migrate it to another machine. But don't know how to keep it's data together.

`docker inspect` told me that the current data is located in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/c27...d02/_data`. Do i just need to copy this folder and move to another machine together? Need your help guys :(

Answer (score 1):

Simply keep that directory as a volume. Have you read the [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb/)? Especially the `Where to Store Data` part

```
-v /var/lib/mysql
```

When you migrate to another machine, simply copy&paste that directory to its counterpart on the another server.

Comment: yes. of course i read the docu before upload this question here. anyway, thx.